rookie — generate AES key with Password, persist and back
As a real crypto rookie, I'd like to use the Web Cryptography API to enable a user to save encrypted data, such that each Item is encrypted separately. As a first step I'd like to:

ask the user for a password,
use that password to create/generate an AES key,
encrypt data with that key and save it
save the key, encrypted in such a way that it can be decrypted by using the password from 1.

When the user provides the password for that item, the plain text data should be returned.
As far as I have been reading the API there are several steps involved.

Key Derivation from a password.
Encryption / Decryption of the data
Encryption / Decryption aka. wrapKey() and unwrapKey()

The actual en- and decryption of the data is not what concerns me most here. The outline of the implementation that I would follow would look like this:
Create an encrypted Item:

ask for password p
create a hash h from that password (sha-256 or sha-512)
Generate a key k as described in step 1 above (key derivation)
encrypt data and save it as ${h}.bin
use wrapKey to encrypt the key (as described here), persist the result as ${h}.key

Restore an Item:

ask for Password p
create hash h from that password
if there are any files matching that hash:,
use unwrapKey to get the key k (described here)
finally decrypt Data using k and return

The things that I really like to know:

how bad is the idea to directly put the password into as hash function
how bad is the idea to use this hash to name files
are there any »heavy duty« rookie mistakes in that approach, or would that do for a first step implementation?


You can't get more wrong than the RSA engineers that developed PKCS #5 if you follow their specification correctly.

PBKDF2 is no longer considered (and never has really been) a robust way to transform a password into a key. While it's better than nothing, it's one of the most vulnerable password-based key derivation functions given the wide availability and progress of GPUs and other massively parallel computing devices. The state of the art is memory hard key stretching. Replacement functions include Argon2 and Scrypt.


how bad is the idea to directly put the password into as hash function

That's what you do in a sense when using PBKDF2 as that only uses hashes as underlying primitives. So that's not bad in itself.

how bad is the idea to use this hash to name files

Extremely bad. You'd allow an attacker to use a bruteforce / dictionary attack to try and find the password, which they can validate using the hash function. In other words: all the security added by using PBKDF2 would be undone.

are there any »heavy duty« rookie mistakes in that approach, or would that do for a first step implementation?

The major problem here is that the user still relies entirely on the security of the server. If that server is taken over or spoofed then the user loses all security and gives the password away to the attacker. That's a fundamental problem with WebCrypto rather than a rookie mistake. The other major mistake is highlighted.

Thanks a lot! To fix the »password hash as filename« problem, I guess I need to find some other way to »derive« the items file name. Would the hash of the files content be a less bad idea then?

That works but could leak information regarding the file content(ie I want to know if I share the same file as you).

@philipp What oaky says. I'm not sure why you want to hide the filename. A very simple scheme would be to randomize it, but that won't let you look it up.
